# Import image with vanilla-extract and esbuild

Tags: esbuild, vanilla-extract

I have a problem with images importing using **vanilla-extract** and **esbuild**

my build file:

```js
const { build } = require("esbuild");
const { vanillaExtractPlugin } = require("@vanilla-extract/esbuild-plugin");

(async () => {
  await build({
    entryPoints: ["src/entry.tsx"],
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    platform: "browser",
    outfile: "dist/entry.js",
    plugins: [vanillaExtractPlugin()],
    loader: {
      ".svg": "file",
    },
  });
})();
```

my **entry.tsx**

```
import { someStyle } from "./style.css";
console.log(someStyle);
```

When i importing my image in "css" way

```
import { style } from "@vanilla-extract/css";

export const someStyle = style({
  backgroundColor: "url(./x.svg)",
});
```

The compiler return error

> Could not resolve "./x.svg" (the plugin "vanilla-extract" didn't set a resolve directory)`

If i am trying to import x.svg using the typescript import

```
import { style } from "@vanilla-extract/css";
import svg from "./x.svg";

export const someStyle = style({
  backgroundColor: `url(${svg})`,
});
```

I have other error

> src/style.css.ts:5:16: error: No loader is configured for ".svg" files: src/x.svg'

Is it possible to import images with **vanilla-extract** modules without marking them as **external**?

Answer (score 0):

It not working now. Workaround is to use babel

```js
import babel from 'esbuild-plugin-babel';
plugins: [
    babel({
        filter: /.*.css.ts/,
        config: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
            plugins: ['@vanilla-extract/babel-plugin'],
        },
    }),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that vanilla-extract runs its own internal esbuild. You need to configure this internal esbuild with necessary loader config or plugin for SVG handling.

The following config should work:

```
 ...

 plugins: [
   vanillaExtractPlugin({
      esbuildOptions: {
        loader: {
          '.svg': 'file'
        }
      }
    }),
  ]
```